# JavaFX: Why are Window.xProperty() and Window.yProperty() read only when there are setters?

Tags: java, javafx

As the title suggests, `Window.xProperty()` and `Window.yProperty()` are both defined as `ReadOnlyDoubleProperty`. However, there are `Window.setX()` and `Window.setY()` that allow us to set the values. Is there any reason why it is designed this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained in the [documentation of `Stage`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html):

> Many of the `Stage` properties are read only because they can be changed externally by the underlying platform and therefore must not be bindable.

While this is stated for `Stage` the reasoning applies to some of the properties of [`Window`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Window.html) as well. In fact, properties like `width`, `height`, and `focused` all mention the same thing:

> The property is read only because it can be changed externally by the underlying platform and therefore must not be bindable.

I don't know why the `x` and `y` properties don't also have this sentence in their documentation, though I'd guess it's just an oversight.

Comment: It definitely sounds convincing when `width` and `height` mentioned that, since these 4 usually work hand-in-hand. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

xProperty() and yProperty() return a Property object which contains the value of x and y respectively. setX() and setX() change x and y, not the Property objects.